# How to force popup to open above anchor in android?

Tags: android, popupmenu

I have a layout with FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, because I need status bar with no background. But this also sets the navigation bar with no background and removes layout limits (as it states in the name), therefore when I click an menu item in bottom of the screen, the popupmenu is opened under the anchor and goes outside of the screen. I would like to force the popupmenu to open above the anchor in screen like it did when there was no layout_no_limits flag.